# MySQLi doesn't update my query/queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Hello, i have a problem updating my tables in my database. sorry if this question is already asked but all of the questions asked didn't solve my problem. Hope stackoverflowcommunity consider this**

i have tables - (orglist, announcements, and memberslist)
i want to update them in any possible mysql functions. I have tried:

**First** method i used was: 3 mysqli_query (3 update queries)

```
if((mysqli_query($conn, orglistupdate) && mysqli_query($conn, announcementsupdate) && (mysqli_query($conn, memberslistupdate))
```

**Second** was i used the function `mysqli_multi_query`

and the **last one** was using join   *Ex. below*

```
$update = "
UPDATE orglist, announcements, memberslist
    SET orglist.orgName = '$orgname', 
        orglist.subjectArea = '$subjectarea',
        orglist.schoolyear = '$sy',
        orglist.semester = '$sem',
        memberslist.orgName = '$orgname',
        announcements.orgName = '$orgname'
    WHERE orglist.managerID = '$managerID' AND
          orglist.orgCode = '$validationOrgCode' AND
          memberslist.orgName = '$validationOrgName' AND
          memberslist.orgCode = '$validationOrgCode' AND
          announcements.orgName = '$validationOrgName' AND
          announcements.orgCode = '$validationOrgCode'";
```

all of the methods I used didnt update my tables.
the thing is it didnt even give me an error so i can fix the problem.

any help will be a great help thank you.

Comment: I suggest to make relation with PK instead of text. You r using orgname in all table. Just suggestion

Comment: And one more thing any where clause failed than query will not insert data in other tables so one more suggestion break query in three parts u can easily handle it.

Comment: im really new to php, all of my relationship is based on orgname, orgcode and managerID

Comment: My friend can u plz echo your query and run in phpmyadmin and chk what u get

Comment: And also share here your which u get after echo

Comment: no error sir. phpmyadmin just reloaded the page

Comment: And in ist method whre u r using seperate mysqli_query function run one by one not use AND just for testing u will get the problem may be all three have error or may be one or two

Comment: And how many rows effected shown in message

Comment: ill start again, review everything

Comment: Mysql_query use separate not use any if conditions when u test than u can do it as u want atleast u will get the idea either connection issue or all queries have issues

Comment: i think error came from my queries. thanks

Comment: add `or die(mysql_error())` after the mysql query call.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

First, if you are using mysqli_, then use parameters in your queries, rather than string substitutions.  This is a good habit to get into.

Next, you are doing the update without any formal join conditions between the tables.  If any of the conditions fail to match (say if one of the tables has no matching `orgcode` or `orgname`), then there are no rows.

Most importantly, though, your data is not normalized.  Why are you storing both `orgcode` and `orgname` in `announcements` and `memberslist`?  You should be storing the organization name in one table (I am guessing either `orglist` or something where `orgcode` is a primary key).  Then, you should be updating *only* that table.  You can access the name when you need it by joining in the other tables.

Comment: thanks for answering, i need to update this 3 tables because each table has an organization name.

Comment: moreover, every table has orgcode field because im using orgcode to other purposes

Comment: @JarvisMillan . . . You should store the organization name in only one table.   I think this is the first rule of normalization:  only store data once.

Comment: i realized what you mean, instead of giving my tables orgname and orgcode, why not i should call them to my orglist table, i have my managerID that i can use